# How to delete a row when all columns are less than one

Tags: sed, awk

I have a matrix file

```
a  0.34  3.03  1.92
b  1.35  1.34  0.63
c  0.66  2.32  1.01
d  0.23  2.07  0.22
e  0.34  0.47  0.55
```

I have to remove rows where all values of its column are less than 1.

Expected output file is

```
a  0.34  3.03  1.92
b  1.35  1.34  0.63
c  0.66  2.32  1.01
d  0.23  2.07  0.22
```

I got this link where they remove row when all columns are less than zero https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592611/how-to-delete-rows-where-all-the-columns-are-zero, where they use rowsums in R. But I don't think row sums will work in this case.

Comment: Reads more like a homework assignment, rather than a support problem experienced by Ubuntu users.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to bioinformatics and the matrix is my RNA seq counts. I gave sample as an simple example.

Comment: I think I can get the result in R by using this  `dat <-data.frame(mat)`
`dat1 = dat[!apply(dat, 1, function(x) all(x < 1)), ]`.  Thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude rows where all (numeric) column values are less than 1, print those for which at least one column has a value greater than or equal to one:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i >= 1){print; next}}' file
a  0.34  3.03  1.92
b  1.35  1.34  0.63
c  0.66  2.32  1.01
d  0.23  2.07  0.22
```

or

```
perl -alne 'shift @F; print if grep { $_ >= 1 } @F' file
```

or (more expressively, using `any` from the List::Util module)

```
perl -MList::Util=any -alne 'shift @F; print if any { $_ >= 1 } @F' file
```

---

Your proposed R command (*posted in comments*) was close: it fails, I think, because you didn't exclude the first (non-numeric) column ex.

```
> dat = read.table("file")
>
> dat
  V1   V2   V3   V4
1  a 0.34 3.03 1.92
2  b 1.35 1.34 0.63
3  c 0.66 2.32 1.01
4  d 0.23 2.07 0.22
5  e 0.34 0.47 0.55
>
> dat[!apply(dat, 1, function(x) all(x < 1)), ]
  V1   V2   V3   V4
1  a 0.34 3.03 1.92
2  b 1.35 1.34 0.63
3  c 0.66 2.32 1.01
4  d 0.23 2.07 0.22
5  e 0.34 0.47 0.55
>
```

but

```
> dat[!apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x < 1)), ]
  V1   V2   V3   V4
1  a 0.34 3.03 1.92
2  b 1.35 1.34 0.63
3  c 0.66 2.32 1.01
4  d 0.23 2.07 0.22
>
```

Comment: The number of the rows I got after using the `R command` I mentioned was 469 and after using the `awk` was `710` . I checked using `comm` and found `R command` has missed some rows whose column values are more than one. I don't know why. But thank you.

Comment: To remove rows when all columns values are zero can I use `dat[!apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x == 0)), ]`, where my first column is row names?..  Few example row names are : `rna71370`, `rna71401`.